# How can you be notified if an AsyncCallback to an asynchronous request has been completed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, mono

In [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx) example an asynchronous request is made and when it has completed, another asynchronous request is made from its callback. How could I be notified from the first thread (main) when the second callback is completed? Normally I would monitor the IAsyncResult, but the creation of the second request is not done in the scope of the first thread, so I don't have access to it.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?  Do you have access to the TPL?

Comment: Mono 2.6 which is roughly equivalent to .net 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get around this is probably not to do it - the second callback could be made syncronous (using `GetResponse` instead of `BeginGetResponse`), then you can just monitor the IAsyncResult.

Alternatively you could also use the same method they use to keep the main thread from ending: create another

```
private static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

then use in the first callback

```
allDone.WaitOne();
```

and call

```
allDone.Set();
```

in the second callback

Comment: That is a very good point, thanks. Just out of curiousity, do you know if the same rules apply to asynchronous requests as do threads- such as the ability to use mutexes and whatnot?

Comment: I think all the same rules apply - the async calls just spawn on a thread from the threadpool rather than being done manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback has to signal the first thread that it is done. It can do so using an event for example. `TaskCompletionSource` is an await-friendly alternative.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in my original post that I require this for Mono 2.6 (.net 3.5 equivalent).

Comment: @Ford why wouldn't the event solution work? Doesn't Mono have events?

Comment: If main was actually a method of a class and I used events would there be any way to match up event callbacks with the instance of the class that started its async request?